# What should I do with this error in python when importing Paraview?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, paraview

I finished the installation of Paraview by conda, but I got an attribute error when importing paraview.simple in jupyter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-51050ddfbc7e> in <module>
----> 1 import paraview.simple

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paraview\simple.py in <module>
     39 
     40 import paraview
---> 41 from paraview import servermanager
     42 import paraview._backwardscompatibilityhelper
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paraview\servermanager.py in <module>
   3372     SetActiveConnection(activeConnection)
   3373 
-> 3374 __initialize()
   3375 
   3376 if hasattr(sys, "ps1"):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paraview\servermanager.py in __initialize()
   3354     # Monitor connection creations/deletions on the ProcessModule.
   3355     pm = vtkProcessModule.GetProcessModule()
-> 3356     pm.AddObserver("ConnectionCreatedEvent", __connectionCreatedCallback)
   3357     pm.AddObserver("ConnectionClosedEvent", __connectionClosedCallback)
   3358 

AttributeError: 'paraview.modules.vtkRemotingCore.vtkProcessModule' object has no attribute 'AddObserver'
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Any reason why you posted the exact same questions from 10 hours ago?

Comment: Thought this title may interest more people. @Reti43